# Gauss divergence theorem, $div(F) = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, surface-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following problem using the Gauss divergence theorem. I 
have to calculate the Flux of

$$
f(x,y,z) =  (\sin(yz),y+\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}, 1-z)
$$

through the surface

$$ \Omega = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 = 1, 0 < z <1  \} $$

The divergence of f is $0$, so evaluating $\int_\Omega div(f)d\Omega $ doesn't give me the solution. I tried to calculate $ \oint_{E =\partial\Omega}f \cdot n  $ d$E$, but I don't know exactly how to do this. Can anybody held me? What exactly is $d\Omega$ and how should I parameterize it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you cannot apply the Divergence Theorem until you close up the surface. Put the top and bottom faces on your cylinder, and *then* the net flux will be $0$. So now calculate (directly) the flux outwards across the top and bottom.